# Type/assembly loading differences between .NET Framework and .NET Core 6 / 7

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-assembly

I'm converting an old .NET Framework 4.7.2 project to .NET 7.

In that project some types are loaded dynamically from external assemblies, like

```
var type = Type.GetType("MyType, MyAssembly")
```

where `MyType` is a type name with all namespaces specified, `MyAssembly` is an assembly name - no .dll in the end, no public key or culture. A partial name. The assembly file which in this case would be `MyAssembly.dll` is in the same directory as the executing file.

It works in net 4.7.2. In net 7 the type is not loaded.

Some articles suggest that in spite of what is written in GetType's documentation it is not going to automatically load an assembly.

So I tried to load it first.

```
Assembly.Load("MyAssembly"); // doesn't work, an exception file not found
Assembly.Load(/* MyAssembly full quantified assembly name */ ); // the same
Assembly.LoadWithPartialName("MyAssembly"); // the same
AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyName( new AssemblyName("MyAssembly") ); // the same
Assembly.LoadFrom("MyAssembly.dll"); // works!
```

And after the assembly is somehow loaded, the original GetType line works too.

So the question would be what is the proper way to load an assembly from the application folder having a partial name, or, better, how to immediately load an assembly and get a type.

I see there are `GetType` and `Assembly.Load` overloads with assembly resolution methods but why should I resolve an assembly from the application directory?

Also, guessing assembly file name from an assembly name provided in an external configuration file by adding ".dll" in the end doesn't look like a safe approach.

Comment: Perhaps check this [.net runtime issue's](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/81341#issuecomment-1408464344) response and the [managed assembly loading algorithm docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/dependency-loading/loading-managed).